# Generics: Array of type expected

Tags: generics, types, compiler-warnings, toarray, enumset

I have the following code:

```
public class DEF implements Set<ABC> {

   private EnumSet<ABC> xyz=EnumSet.noneOf(ABC.class);

   @Override
   public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
       return xyz.toArray(a);
   }

}
```

Which gives me the following warning:

Array of type 'ABC[]' expected at line 43

Is this dangerous? Or can I ignore it? Why is this warning?

Comment: Why do you think that `T` is `ABC`?

Comment: I've edited. Does it make any sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is completely correct; your code makes no sense.

By writing `<T> T[] toArray()`, you've made a function that can be called with *any* type parameter and will return an array of that type.
Always returning an array of `ABC`s violates what you claimed it will do.

In short, that function should not be generic.

---

None of this is applicable to your case, because the base `Set<E>` interface requires this.

I have no idea why `Set<E>` is declared that way, but there is nothing you can do about the warning.

Comment: But if I override the method, then I can not change the method signature, can I?

Comment: @user2254314: You're right; I have no idea why the base version is generic.  In this case, you have no choice but to ignore the warning.

Comment: If you re-edit your answer I will upvote it and check it as an answer.